# Unitary matrices as a function of Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My books says that a unitary matrix $U$ can be written as:

$ U = A + i B$

where $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian and are related by:

$A^2 + B^2 = I$

where $I$ is the identity matrix.
However, I cannot seem to find any proof of this statement and struggling to understand why that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any square matrix $U$ with complex entries can be written in the form $U=A+iB$ with $A,B$ Hermitian by setting
$$ A=\frac{U+U^*}{2}$$
and
$$ B=\frac{U-U^*}{2i}$$
If also $U$ is unitary, then $U^*U=UU^*=I$, and it follows that
$$ A^2+B^2=\frac{1}{4}(U+U^*)^2-\frac{1}{4}(U-U^*)^2=I$$

To understand the motivation behind the definitions of $A$ and $B$, it might be useful to think of the one dimensional case, when matrices are just complex numbers, Hermitian matrices correspond to real numbers, and unitary matrices to complex numbers with modulus one.

Comment: Does $U^*$ stand for the complex conjugate or the Hermitian conjugate of $U$?

Comment: $U^*$ is the adjoint, which is given by conjugating every entry of $U$ and then transposing $U$.

Comment: From my understanding if $U = A + iB$, then if I conjugate every entry of $U$ I should obtain $A - iB$. Why is the transposing needed? Wouldn't that modify $A$ and $B$ also?

Comment: Do you know what it means for a matrix to be unitary or hermitian?

Comment: Well to my knowledge a matrix $M$ is Hermitian if its complex conjugate transposed (denoted with $^H$) is equal to its transpose, in other words $M^H = M^T$. A unitary matrix $U$ is one which obeys $U^{-1} = U^H$. What I don't understand from your answer is that according to my knowledge $(A + iB)^H = A^H + iB^H \ne A- iB$.

Comment: The notation $M^H$ means the same thing as the $M^*$ which I used in my answer. A matrix is Hermitian if $M^H=M$, not $M^H=M^T$. And also $(A+iB)^H=A^H-iB^H$ since the complex conjugate of $i$ is $-i$.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies it. I had understood the definition completely wrong.